# I cannot install axios in my React project

Tags: reactjs, axios, tailwind-css, yarnpkg

Currently, I am building the AI Image-Generator, but I couldn't install axios after adding Tailwind CSS to project.

The attached image is as follows.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWEHx.png)

The command that I tried for axios is as follows.

```
yarn add axios
```

Comment: Try `yarn install`. Does it end up well ? My guess is that your dependencies are corrupted. postcss, try reinstalling tailwind if you are using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue occurred because of node version.
I downgraded node version, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your postcss dependency is corrupted somehow.
Try removing then reinstalling tailwind dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Try it using npm:

```
npm install axios
```